# Print without "print dialogue" in node-webkit

Tags: javascript, webkit, chromium, node-webkit, chromium-embedded

While building an app using **node-webkit** for **windows**, I need to print without the dialogue box. Is this possible?

> Similar to: http://drziegler.net/kiosksilent-printing-in-google-chrome/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is still unimplemented at this point.  There is an issue on github for it, and it seemed to be a very popular feature request.

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/56

Printing support was just added in April,  This was in the release notes for 0.50.

- Printing support (#56): window.print() works now. The print preview feature is not included yet. We plan to add it before 0.5.2 release.

Comment: The current release is [0.9.2](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/releases). Is this feature implemented yet? If yes, how do I enable it?

Comment: I just called window.print() and my standard print dialog opened, and it worked.  Keep in mind this still won't solve your original request for printing without the dialog box.

Comment: Please post without dialog box printing with node-webkit, very urgent.

Comment: At this point this is an open issue, and labelled as silent printing. https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1263 .  It currently has a $100 bounty.

Comment: So the silent printing feature implemented yet ?

Comment: @Mohtashim Yes, you have to add the option `autoprint:true` and `silent:true` check this : https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#winprintoptions

Answer (score 0):

You can now do it by adding add the option `autoprint:true` and `silent:true`
Find it in the docs: https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#winprintoptions